# jQuery fadeOut, replaceWith, animate almost working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

I am trying to accomplish the following:
1. On click, have a div with id="fader" fadeout
2. replaceHtml of fader with new html (this new HTML will appear below the fold of the browser)
3. Animate new HTML to slide up to the specified location

Step 1 and 2 are working, step 3 is not and I'm stumped as to why.

Here's the javascript:

```
$("#fader").fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<div id=\"fader\" style=\"margin-top:-500px;width:500px;height:400px;border:1px solid black;\">new div</div>', function() {
    $("#fader").animate({marginTop: "500px"});
  });
});
```

Any thoughts on why the div won't animate would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jesse - If you can, accept answers by clicking the checkmark beside the on the one that helped you resolve the issue, helps keep all of SO tidy and your questions appealing to answer.

Comment: Try also my func.. let me know! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) has no callback, it's has a different signature than animations have.

Try this instead:

```
$("#fader").fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<div id="fader" style="margin-top:-500px;width:500px;height:400px;border:1px solid black;">new div</div>');
  $("#fader").animate({marginTop: "500px"});
});
```

Note you can't chain this, `.replaceWith()` returns the **original** object, not the one you just created.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on .replaceWith() and chaining.  The code snippet you provided is working, I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm confused about what you're saying: 1) .replaceWith() has no callback, period; not just in this case. And 2) He wasn't chaining anything in his initial code (unless he edited the code before I saw it). Chaining is like `$('.class').replaceWith('<p></p>').fadeIn();`, or am I wrong?

Comment: @dclowd9901 - If you removed the `$("#fader")` in `$("#fader").animate({marginTop: "500px"});` then it wouldn't work...normally you can shorten by the same selector, I was pointing out that removing that selector in this case won't work, so don't try to optimize that :)

Comment: Perfect. Been struggling with chaining animation events for a while now!