# How do I extend jQuery's replaceWith function to accept a callback function?

Tags: jquery, callback

This should be easy, right? Yet I can't sem to find any examples of such a functionality anywhere. The problem is that after I do a replaceWith() I want to then do something with those elements that were written to the DOM, but if I try to do something to them right after the replaceWith() call they don't exist yet so I need to be sure the replaceWith() is completely finished. I just want something like this to work:

```
$('#foo').replaceWith('some text', function() {
     //do something else here
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you show the code that isn't working when you try to do the processing it immediately afterwards? `replaceWith` is not asynchronous, so this should work fine. *Edit* My bet is that you're trying to do something with `#foo` still, but it won't exist because you just replaced it...

Comment: Why do you need a callback if `replaceWith` is not asynchronous? You can call your method right away after calling `replaceWith`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465431/jquery-fadeout-replacewith-animate-almost-working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248721/jquery-replacewith-fade-animate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your own function that calls `replaceWith`:

```
$.fn.replaceWithCallback = function(replace, callback){
    var ret = $.fn.replaceWith.call(this, replace); // Call replaceWith
    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
       callback.call(ret); // Call your callback
     }
    return ret;  // For chaining
};
```

Comment: I know I am very late at this but might help others. This is not the right solution for this question. Although a function will be called as is one of his requirement, it can't possibly work as a callback. He mentioned clearly in his requirements that "if I try to do something to them right after the replaceWith() call they don't exist yet so I need to **be sure the replaceWith() is completely finished**". It might work as somehow replaceWith returns before the function executes, but that would be just luck. So I would recommend not to use this method to create a callback.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik: `replaceWith` is synchronous.  My guess is he was trying to use a cached jQuery object.  Like `var $a = $('#foo'); $a.replaceWith('a');`.  Trying to use `$a` won't work, as the element doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I had the same issue, trying this: `toUpdate.find('.inscription').replaceWith(inscription);` `initAddInscription(toUpdate.find('.inscription'));`

Answer (score 0):

Create callback functionality simply by doing:

```js
$("#myElement").replaceWith(function() {
  // call a function
);
```

and to replace a word and not inner html:

```js
$("#derp").text(function(index, text) {
  // call a function here
  return text.replace('old', 'new');
});
```